# 404 page not found Traefik Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I can't access to my services via Traefik Ingress. When i request to machine host 192.168.1.2/elastisearch i receive a 404 response from Traefik.
When i inspect the ingress i get
 `elasticsearch-api-clusterip:9200 (<error: endpoints "elasticsearch-api-clusterip" not found>)` but elasticsearch-api-clusterip endpoint exists

````
Name:              elasticsearch-api-clusterip
Namespace:         elastic
Labels:            app=elasticsearch
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=elasticsearch
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.108.147.198
Port:              <unset>  9200/TCP
TargetPort:        9200/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.44:9200,10.244.2.13:9200,10.244.4.15:9200
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>```

This is my ingress

kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: "v-ingress"
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /elasticsearch
        backend:
          serviceName: elasticsearch-api-clusterip
          servicePort: 9200
      - path: /traefik-ui
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
````

The request to endpoint give me a response from the service.

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Does the 404 error appears every time or just once? What exactly is giving it? Traefik? App?

Comment: Thank you for you response. Always 404, traefik works but for all request get 404

Comment: The 404 status code, or a `Not Found` error, means that the user is able to communicate with the server but it is unable to locate the requested file or resource. Could you check if your paths exists and are correctly configured?